# Fitting of bivariate data to a self-defined probability density function

Tags: dataset, fitting, likelihood, extreme-value

I have a bivariate set of data points which I want to fit to a self-defined distribution (i.e. not standard normal or chi-square or like that, a different, let's say "new" density function).  I would wish to fit it via method of maximum likelihood, but my density function has 2 infinite sums in it so strictly speaking I don't have a closed form expression.  The density function is also quite a clumsy expression.

I know about the "nlm" function in R, but I have a very limited knowledge about R.  I am very familiar with SAS and fairly familiar with Mathematica.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can proceed?  Thus, for a given set of bivariate data and a self-defined bivariate density function, I wish to estimate 5 parameters via the method of maximum likelihood.

Hoping someone can help me :)

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `PROC KDE` may do what you want.